# Istio: How do I exclude unhealthy destination from a VirtualService?

Tags: kubernetes, failover, istio

I'm trying to configure load balancing and failover for *external* services. Each HTTP endpoint for the service needs its own specific headers.

I created a virtual service with two destinations:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: test-external
spec:
  hosts:
  - test-external.com
  http:
  - headers:
      request:
        set:
          test: "true"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: "201.returnco.de"
      weight: 50
      headers:
        request:
          set:
            Host: "201.returnco.de"
            api-key: "xxxxxxxxxx"
    - destination:
        host: "501.returnco.de"
      weight: 50
      headers:
        request:
          set:
            Host: "501.returnco.de"
            api-key: "yyyyyyyyyy"
    retries: {}
```

The hosts `201.returnco.de` and `501.returnco.de` are external services, so I created a service entry for them.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: test-external
spec:
  hosts:
  - test-external.com
  - 201.returnco.de
  - 501.returnco.de
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: http
    number: 80
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: DNS
```

What I want is to route requests only to `201.returnco.de`. The requests should not be routed to a host which returns 5xx status code. In this case, `501.returnco.de` always returns 5xx status code, so it is considered unhealthy.

How should I configure the mesh?

---

I tried making the following destination rule, but this doesn't work.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: test-external
spec:
  host: "*.returnco.de"
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      baseEjectionTime: 1m
      consecutive5xxErrors: 1
      consecutiveGatewayErrors: 1
      interval: 15s
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
```

The mesh considers `201.returnco.de` and `501.returnco.de` as two separate services. After the unhealthy endpoint for the host `501.returnco.de` is evicted, Istio proxy returns 503 error for requests because there are no healthy endpoints.

Configuring multiple endpoints for a single service is not ideal because I need to set different headers for each endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

From your configs and description, it is understood that you are creating multiple endpoints for the same service. In this scenario if you use **“*.returnco.de”** in your **DestinationRule** for **OutlierDetection,** when you receive **5xx errors** for the endpoint [501.returnco.de](http://501.returnco.de) as you mentioned it will evict the pods. Since [201.returnco.de](http://201.returnco.de) is another endpoint of the same service which inturn relies on the same pods you are getting 503 errors because the pods are already evicted. In order to prevent the pods from getting evicted you can directly mention [201.returnco.de](http://201.returnco.de) in your DestinationRule as we already know [501.returnco.de](http://501.returnco.de) returns the 5xx errors and will evict the pods, below is the modified **DestinationRule** for your reference

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: test-external
spec:
  host: 201.returnco.de
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      baseEjectionTime: 1m
      consecutive5xxErrors: 1
      consecutiveGatewayErrors: 1
      interval: 15s
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
```

Also if you don’t want your requests to be routed to [501.returnco.de](http://501.returnco.de) you can give less weight such as 0 to [501.returnco.de](http://501.returnco.de) rule and some high weight such as 100 to [201.returnco.de](http://201.returnco.de) rule or use the **[explicit deny](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-deny/)** option of Istio.

Comment: `501.returnco.de` is just an example to emulate the failure on a service. In practice I don't know when or which destination will return 5xx errors, so I cannot simply hardcode the configuration.

Comment: @hylowaker I gave this solution because of unique use case you mentioned in the description. In general if you don't want to have multiple services you should omit outlier detection configuration for the endpoints, as both the endpoints exist on the same pod it will evict the pods as a result you will continuously get the 5xx errors.

Comment: @hylowaker have you gone through my reply.., revert back if you are still facing some issues.

Comment: I didn't find a solution with Istio-alone so I implemented my own Envoy Filter for this.

Comment: @hylowaker can you provide your solution here so that it will be helpful for remaining community members.